# How do I get a _received_ iCal event to run a script?

Tags: applescript, skype, icalendar

I'm trying to write an Applescript that will make an outgoing Skype call at times scheduled by *received* invites from other parties.

I think I'm fine with the script to Skype's API to make the call, however I'm struggling with iCal with either method of

A) getting the script to run in the background and getting the time of all new events, or

B) getting the event alert to run a one-off script.

The issue with option B) is that although you can set events from within iCal so that the alert runs a script, I need to trigger this from events that have been received.

A typical example would be:

- All scripts and iCal running on the Host
- At 10am a User schedules an event (via google cal on portable device) for 3pm** and invites the the Host.
- At 3pm the script on the Host uses Skype API to make a call to the User.

** this could just as equally be on a date in the future and the requirements still hold.

Many thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iCal doesn't have any notifications (some applications do like iChat) you'll have to run a "stay open" applescript application. Something like this will do it for your "B" scenario. NOTE: you will have to add the path to your applescript file (the one that makes your Skype call) in the "applescriptPath" variable.

When launched it will get a listing of all the calendar events you have in iCal. It will then run itself every 5 minutes. When it runs it will check the current events against the list of events it originally made. If there are new events then your applescript will be added as an alarm to the new events. This way it keeps track of the current events between runs and only finds the new ones.

So this script should be a good starting point for you. Remember to save it as a stay-open applescript application. You probably will want to modify it. For example I have it checking every calendar for new events but you may have one particular calendar you want to target. Good luck.

```
property storedUIDs : {} -- we use this to check for new events, if an event is not in this list then it is new

global applescriptPath

on run
    set applescriptPath to (path to desktop as text) & "myAlarm.scpt" -- the path to the applescript which is run as the alarm
end run

on idle
    set newEvents to {}
    tell application "iCal"
        set theCals to calendars
        set allUIDs to {}
        repeat with aCal in theCals
            tell aCal
                set theseEvents to events
                repeat with anEvent in theseEvents
                    set thisUID to uid of anEvent
                    set end of allUIDs to thisUID
                    if thisUID is not in storedUIDs then
                        set end of newEvents to contents of anEvent
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell
        end repeat
        set storedUIDs to allUIDs

        if (count of newEvents) is less than 5 then -- this will prevent the first run of the script from adding the alarm to every event
            repeat with aNewEvent in newEvents
                -- do something with this new events like add an alarm to run an applescript
                set theAlarm to make new open file alarm at end of open file alarms of aNewEvent with properties {trigger interval:0, filepath:POSIX path of applescriptPath}
            end repeat
        end if
    end tell

    return (5 * 60) -- run every 5 minutes
end idle

on quit
    set storedUIDs to {}
    continue quit
end quit
```

Comment: Thanks (and appologies for delayed response - hadn't set my email notifications correctly!)

Comment: Ps. Am I right in thinking the On idle /// end idle routine is run after the script has been run?

Comment: Yes Dan, the "on idle" handler is the one that is run repeatedly. This is why you make it a stay-open application... so that is run. You see that just before the end statement we "return 300" which tells the idle handler to run every 300 seconds. So at launch the "on run" and "on idle" handlers are run, then every 300 seconds the "on idle" handler is run again. When you right-click the dock icon and quit, the "on quit" handler is run. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much for you help - this gives me a great starting point and plenty to experiment with.

Comment: I've tested it out (and modified it accordingly to run the Skype script) and it works great for iCal events created locally, but when I test it with an invite from a Google Calendar these events show in the iCal calendar but don't seem to get picked up by the AppleScript?

Comment: I don't use google calendar so I'm not sure. You need to check if the calendar with those events are showing the events. Just test a separate script... tell app "ical", tell calendar "calendar name", return events, end tell, end tell. Look and see if you get a list of events from that calendar. If so then you're good and there's something you can fix in the script code. If not then that's the problem and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Great - I'll try this. I managed to modify the script to cycle through the calandars available and return their name, so I'm comfortable the google mail calandar is there, but I also notice that those events are already showing 3 alerts so I wonder if by placing the script alert at the end is causing the issue.

Comment: I'll try inserting the alarm at a different point in the order and report back.

Comment: Nice - just tested your suggestion and I get a list of events from @google returned so I'll experiment from here...

Comment: Here's an odd one : If I modify your last script to ...tell app "iCal", tell calendar "calendar name", repeat with AnEvent in events, return AnEvent, end repeat, end tell, end tell.... instead of each event I get "item 1 of every event of calendar 'calendar name' of app ical". Why would this be different?

Comment: It's the way you have your repeat loop. You are using a reference to the event when you use "repeat with AnEvent in events"... "AnEvent" is a reference. You can see from my original code I'm doing the same but when I want the actual event I get the "contents" of the event, which de-references it. Try "return contents of AnEvent".

Comment: Ah okay. I've just updated to 'return contents of AnEvent' and now it down return the event, but only one event. Whereas when I did your script it returned all of the events.